# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, pdo

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:42
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 42

index.php

```
<?php
                         $db = new DB();
                         $stmt = $db->pdo->prepare("SELECT film_name, film_small_img FROM new_film");
                         $stmt->execute();
                   ?>
                   <?php foreach ($stmt as $row): ?>
                     <a href="films/<?php echo $row['film_name']; ?>.php">
                       <img src="<?php echo $row['film_small_img']; ?>" alt="" style="width: 100px;">
                       <p><?php echo $row['film_name']; ?></p>
                     </a>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
      $config = [
          'title' => 'KinoKings',
          'account_name' => 'meln1337'
        ];

      $settings = [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'main',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4'
      ]
   ?>
```

connection.php

```
class DB {
        /*
          The PDO Object
        */
        public $pdo;
        /*
          Connection to the DB boolean
        */
        private $isConnected;
        /*
          PDO statement object
        */
        //private $stmt;
        /*
          The DB options
        */
        // protected $opt = [
        //   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        //   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        //   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        // ];
        /*
          The database settings
        */
        protected $settings = [];

        /*
          The parameters of the SQL query
        */
        private $parametres = [];
        /*
          Database constructor
        */
        public function __constructor (array $settings) {

          $this->settings = $settings;

          $this->connect();

        }
        /*
          Connect to database
        */
        private function connect () {

          $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->settings['dbname'] . ';host=' . $this->settings['host'];

          try {
            $this->pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $this->settings['user'], $this->settings['password'], [
              \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES ' . $this->settings['charset']
            ]);

            // Disable emulations and we can now log
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $this->isConnected = true;

          } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
          }
        }

        public function closeConnection () {
          $this->pdo = null;
        }

        private function init () {
          if (!$this->isConnected) {
            $this->connect();
          }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Помогите исправить ошибку, пж.

Comment: У вас нет подключения к БД, проверьте настройки свои

Comment: Я переправил $settings['user'] на $settings['username'] но ошибка осталась

Comment: `public function __constructor (array $settings) {` ... Во-первых, вы, наверное, очепятались, да? `__constructor` сменить на `__construct`.. Во-вторых, у вас конструктор говорит что должны передаваться параметры подключения. `$db = new DB();` - где они? Ну и, в-третьих, в `private function connect () {}` нужен `return`, я полагаю.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php - Разберитесь хоть изначально как "магические" методы в ООП называются и как им передавать данные, вообще научитесь правильно создавать экземпляры классов.